# callback vs async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code, that implements `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` singals handling in node.js app.

```
// quit on ctrl+c when running docker in terminal
process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
  console.info('Got SIGINT (aka ctrl+c in docker). Graceful shutdown', new Date().toISOString());
  await gracefulShutdown(server);
});

// quit properly on docker stop
process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
  console.log('Got SIGTERM (docker container stop).Graceful shutdown', new Date().toISOString());
  await gracefulShutdown(server);
});
```

Here I am passing, in both cases, an `async` callback function that shutsdown the app.

If chose not to do `await` inside the callback it becomse as below.

```
// quit properly on docker stop
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      console.log('Got SIGTERM (docker container stop).Graceful shutdown', new Date().toISOString());
      gracefulShutdown(server);
    });
```

What is the difference between this normal callback and async callback above regarding execution order or execution in general?

Does both differ or they are the same?

Here is `gracefulShutdown()` handler

```
const { sequelize } = require('../models');

module.exports = async (server) => {
  try {
    await sequelize.close();
    console.info('Closed database connection!');
    await server.close();
    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.info(error.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions will immediately start executing *until* they hit the first `await` statement or when they end.

So given that you're just calling `console.log` and `gracefulShutdown`, either executes in the same order.

The two will be different in terms of how errors are handled, what is returned, but I don't think it makes a difference for this case.

I'd recommend in each case that you do some error handling on `gracefulShutdown` if it *can* throw an error

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, if this was not an event but and api call to some other server like `fetch('http://example.com/api/users', (data) => console.log(data));` ..and in another case `async (data) => console.log(data)`. Will in later case undefined will be logged? As you said it starts executing immediately. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense for `fetch()`, there is no callback-style API for it. Perhaps ask a new question on this website and ask what you _really_ want to know?

Comment: I just gave an example, It could be `axios` or anything else. Please read the later part. If it is an event, but some time taking task.

Comment: Read my answer again. Regardless of how gracefullShutdown works, I don't think there's a material difference